# java generic class extends the generic argument

Tags: java, templates, generics

Short version:

What is the correct syntax to make a class extends its generic argument:

```
 class A<T> extends T {} // doesn't compile
```

Long version:

I have a base abstract class (the following code has been shortened just for this post purposes)

```
abstract class D { 
     abstract void f();
     abstract void g();
}
```

Then, there is a set of possible combinations for each f() and each g(). The goal is to have all the possible combinations.

One solution is to make for each f_j() a class Fj that extends D and implements the f_j(), then for each g_i() we make a class GiFj which extends Fj and implements g_i().
For example

```
abstract class F1 extends D {
    @Override
    void f() { /* F1 Work */ }
}
abstract class F2 extends D {
    @Override
    void f() { /* F2 Work */ }
}
class G1F1 extends F1 {
    @Override
    void g() { /* G1 Work */ }
}
class G1F2 extends F2 {
    @Override
    void g() { /* G1 Work : Duplicated Code */ }
}
```

The problem is that the code for Gi is going to get duplicated many times.

The solution that I want to implement is to regroup all GFi into on generic class

```
class G1<F extends D> extends F {
    @Override
    void g() { /* G1 work */ }
}
```

So how to do this in java, or if it is impossible what is the good way to do it

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like you are wanting multiple inheritance of classes, which is not supported in Java.  Have a look at using the [mixin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587458/implement-mixin-in-java) strategy.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to short version**

That is not possible in Java. A compiler needs to know at compile time which methods and fields the superclass of a class has. Thus, a class can only extend a concrete class (possible with type variables), but it cannot extend a type variable on its own.

**Answer to long version (which on the surface seems to be unrelated to the short version)**

You can use composition to achieve sort of what you want:

```
class Foo {
    final FDelegate fDelegate;
    final GDelegate gDelegate;

    Foo(FDelegate fDelegate, Delegate gDelegate) {
        this.fDelegate = fDelegate;
        this.gDelegate = gDelegate;
    }

    void f() {
        fDelegate.f(this);
    }

    void g() {
        gDelegate.g(this);
    }
}

interface FDelegate {
    void f(Foo container);
}
interface GDelegate {
    void g(Foo container);
}
```

Then you have classes `F1`, `F2`, `G1`, `G2` which contain the various method implementations. You pass a `Foo` object so that you can access its (visible) members.